# Sorting in ArrayAdapter using Android

Tags: android-activity

```
public void refresh() 
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    do {
        String str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) +
                "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) + "\n";
        arrayAdapter.add(str);
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

in the above mentioned code, I want to display my mobile contact names with contact number in listview by using ArrayAdapter. now I obtain the solution in unsorted manner. But I want to display my contacts in sorted order. Can any one help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is to specify the sort order as part of your database query. Like so:

```
Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

You can use SQLite's [`ORDER BY`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) syntax here.

Alternatively, you can use `Collections.sort` to sort your array directly.